# Upgrading memory on an IBM Power 710 Express (8231-E2B)

Tags: memory, aix, ibm, electrical-power

We have a Power 710 Express server that was loaded with 4x4 GB memory on a single riser card. I have replaced the 4 chips with 4x8GB and put in another riser card and loaded it with 4x8GB more for a total of 64GB memory. The firmware is AL730_078.

When i power it on, the service processor boots up and i can access the ASMi.

From here I can look at "Memory Serial Presence Data" and see that the system in some way detects 8x8 GB.

[image: Memory Serial Presence Data]

However when i look at Hardware Deconfiguration and specifically Memory Deconfiguration, it is still listed with old values, 16384MB, and claims there are 4x4 chips in the C17 riser.

[image: Memory Deconfiguration]

How do i proceed to make the server recognize properly the amount of memory installed? I get a `FSPSP04` and `B181B50F` progress code on booting because (i think) it hasn't been told the memory has changed. It then does not proceed to booting the operating system (VIOS) when turned on.

Are there any steps I have overlooked here? Can I do some commands, either on the service processor, or otherwise, to tell the system to configure with the proper amount of memory?

PS: This is a stand alone server, not configured with HMC or SDMC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description it appears that your firmware is not at the correct level for installation of feature 5265 - additional memory card riser. According to the IBM Hardware Prerequisite Tool the required level is ** AL720_066 **.

[IBM Prerequisite Check](https://www-912.ibm.com/e_dir/eserverv7prereq.nsf/UpgradeCategories/Hardware?editdocument)

Cheers

R

Comment: Better late than never. The memory was returned and replaced with another manufacturer that was compatible.